# Have I used __DIR__ correctly?

Tags: php, html, http

I'm using the following to include my config.php and insert my header into each page using:

```
<?php require_once __DIR__."/config.php"; require_once SITE_ROOT."/templates/include/header.php" ?>
```

However, when I do so, I receive the following error:

> Warning: require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/templates/admin/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/templates/admin/listArticles.php on line 1

For referance, this is what config.php looks like:

```html
<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
date_default_timezone_set( "Australia/Sydney" );  // http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms" );
define( "DB_USERNAME", "username" );
define( "DB_PASSWORD", "password" );
define( "CLASS_PATH", "classes" );
define( "TEMPLATE_PATH", "templates" );
define( "HOMEPAGE_NUM_ARTICLES", 5 );
define( "ADMIN_USERNAME", "admin" );
define( "ADMIN_PASSWORD", "mypass" );
define('SITE_ROOT', __DIR__);
require( CLASS_PATH . "/Article.php" );


function handleException( $exception ) {
  echo "Sorry, a problem occurred. Please try later.";
  error_log( $exception->getMessage() );
}

set_exception_handler( 'handleException' );
?>
```

It might also be worth mentioning that I previously recieved an error telling me that SITE_ROOT was not defined, but I have since fixed this by including the directory befoer /config.php.

I've also tried to use the require_once__DIR__ .. elsewhere in the site and it works fine.

What possible reasons are there for seeing the error?

Comment: where you define this line define('SITE_ROOT', __DIR__); ? in which file

Comment: That line is part of config.php as mentioned above. I'll edit the post to include all the contents of config.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your error message

> Warning: require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/templates/admin/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/templates/admin/listArticles.php on line 1

I assume your config.php is not supposed to be in the same path as your templates. It needs to use a relative path, so depending on the actual location of your file (I don't know what this is)

```
<?php require_once __DIR__."/../../config.php"; require_once SITE_ROOT."/templates/include/header.php" ?>
```

Or something like the above based on the actual location of your config.php.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: After looking at the structure of my files I've come to realise that by adding /../ to the path of config.php, you're telling the script to look in the next highest folder. (which is where config.php is located)

Thanks for the fix!

Comment: After looking at the structure of my files I've come to realise that by adding /../ to the path of config.php, you're telling the script to look in the next highest folder. (which is where config.php is located)

Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help :)